# Greek letters with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am struggeling with greek letters in Gnuplot. I followed the advice of other threads and set the terminal to "enhanced" and used the {/Symbol} format, but the code still doesn't print the greek letter. My label is "Tiefe in mm" instead of "Tiefe in µm".

```
set terminal svg enhanced font "arial bold,10" size 800,600 background '#ffffff'
set ylabel "Tiefe in {/Symbol m}m"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I now searched for an hour and found the solution which solved the problem:

I added the line

```
set encoding utf8
```

And after that I was able to simply write the greek letter in my file, no {/Symbol} needed anymore:

```
set ylabel "Tiefe in µm"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use set the terminal to epslatex and then use greek letters. Below is an example script

```
set terminal epslatex color size 5.5in,3.5in standalone
set output 'profile.tex'
set ylabel "$\\textrm{Tiefe in} \\mu$"
pl 'data.txt' u 1:2 w lp ps 2 pt 5 lw 2 lc 7 title 'Data'
unset out
set out
```